# Customizing primaryStage title : centered with icon

Tags: java, javafx, customization, title, stage

I'm working on a school project in Java FX, I'd like to add an icon next to my primarystage title and center the title, just like the one in the picture. I have looked around in the javadoc for Stage but i can only find the setTitle() method. Here is a link to what i'd like to do :

[image]

Comment: [`Stage.getIcons`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html#getIcons())?

Answer (score 0):

You can set your stage to undecorated, set your scene root to a border pane and create your own custom top bar.

```
BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
root.setTop(new Pane(bb, label));
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

ButtonBar topBar = new ButtonBar(… insert buttons in here....);
// eg: Button b = new Button("X); b.setOnAction(e->{stage.close();});
root.setTop(topBar);

stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
```